# slideshow for div's background image + jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, background, slideshow

I have a big div element at header and there are many text contents and some boxes in the div. and i have a big img as bg for this div, now i need to make a slideshow for this div's background :/

How can I make slideshow for a div's background image?

I researched a lot, but could not find anything :/

Thanks a lot! appreciate!

Answer (score 2):

One way of doing this is to make an array of background-images:

```
var bgArr = ["img/bg1.jpg", "img/bg2.jpg"]; //and so on...
function backgroundSlide(i) {
    $("#header").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i++]+")");
    if (i == bgArr.length) i = 0;
    var st = setTimeout(arguments.callee(i), 1000);
}
backgroundSlide(0)
```

This will just loop and loop...

Answer (score 2):

I too was looking for a css background element slideshow, Thanks for your input. I explored your solution with the setTimeout method, however had massive troubles with it (I'm a noob).

I've adapted peirix's solution with a setInterval alternative and came up with this;

```
var bgArr = ["images/TopImage-01.jpg", "images/TopImage-02.jpg", "images/TopImage-03.jpg" ]; 
var i=0;

// Start the slide show
var interval = self.setInterval("swapBkgnd()", 5000)  

function swapBkgnd() {
 if (i>(bgArr.length-1) ) {
  i=0
  $("#header").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i]+")");
 }
 else {
  $("#header").css("background-image", "url("+bgArr[i]+")"); 
 } 
 i++;
};
```

Now I need to add a fade effect and image preloader and I'll be away. Would be interested to know if there's a tidier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to change the background image:

```
$("#mydiv").css("background-image", "url(1.jpg)");
```

In order to create a slideshow, call it at regular intervals by using settimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of day before I have been looking for similar explanation. Answer number two was pretty good but as I can see it needs fade effect. I have accomplished that (and more). Here is the code:

```
var bgArr = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png', 'img4.png']; 
var bgText = ['text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4']; 
var i=0;
var left = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
    timer = setTimeout("changeBG()", 7000);

    $("#slider_left").on("click", function(){
        i = i-2;
        if(i&lt;-1) i = bgArr.length-2;         
                left = 1;       
                clearTimeout(timer);        
                changeBG();     
        });     
        $("#slider_right").on("click", function(){      
                if(i&gt;(bgArr.length-1)) i = 0;
        clearTimeout(timer);
        changeBG();
    });
});

function changeBG() {
    i++;
    if(i&gt;(bgArr.length-1)) i = 0;
    $('#slider_up').stop().fadeIn(1000, function(){
        if(left == 1){
        var a = i+1;
        if(i == bgArr.length-1)
            a = 0;
        }else{
        var a = i-1;
        if(i == 0)
            a = bgArr.length-1;
        }
        left = 0;

        $("#slider_up").css("background", "url("+bgArr[a]+") no-repeat center center white");
        $("#slider_up").css('opacity',0).show().animate({opacity:1});
        $("#slider_down").css("background", "url("+bgArr[i]+") no-repeat center center white");
        $("#slider_up").css('opacity',1).show().animate({opacity:0});
        $(".text_holder").fadeOut(1000, function() {
        $(this).html(bgText[i]);
        $(this).fadeIn(500);
        });
    });
    timer = setTimeout("changeBG()", 7000);
};
```

I have explained it on my blog: http://blog.braovic.com/css-background-slider-and-slideshow/

Hope this helps you all.
Best,
Ante.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you - https://github.com/im4aLL/bose

```
$("#header").bose({
    images : [ "imagePath_1", "imagePath_2", "imagePath_3"]
});
```

But only fade transition. Good luck!