# 10 pixel Shift Website

Tags: html, css, web

I centered some objects on a website, added some images, horizontal lines, etc. Everything works just fine but their remains some kind of 10 or 20 pixel margin on the left that I can´t edit.
My centered Images are thatswhy 10-20 pixels too much on the right an an horizontal top border of a div that has 100% width does only reach from the right end of the screen to 10-20 pixels before the left end of the screen.
Do you have any idea whats could be wrong with my website?

Comment: You've given us no code to look at.

Comment: Did you reset the default margin on the body to 0? `body { margin:0; }`

Comment: Max, please provide both your HTML and CSS for answerers to examine. It would be great if you also created a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net), saved it, and posted the URL.

Comment: Ok, I will do so, just give me a few minutes :)

Comment: Resetting the default margin already did the trick! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Danield Please submit your comment as an answer so that it can be upvoted and marked as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `body` element has a  default margin

[Appendix D. Default style sheet for HTML 4](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/sample.html).

```
body            { margin: 8px }
```

You can simply remove it with `body { margin:0 }`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is this comment:

> Did you reset the default margin on the body to 0? body { margin:0; } – [Danield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459533/slideshow-for-divs-background-image-jquery)

Thanks [Danield](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459533/slideshow-for-divs-background-image-jquery)!